# The meaning of "even as"

Tags: grammar

> Their discovery was also the world’s discovery, and the film conveys the sense of a world out of joint, a total catastrophe that defies comprehension and seems like a sort of ubiquitous madness, **even as** its careful industrial organization becomes **all the clearer**.[Source](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/movies/2014/01/hitchcock-and-the-holocaust.html)

Does this mean just when Nazi Germany's careful industrial organization (a killing system, almost industrial) becomes clearer, this madness at this camp feels more like part of a much broader thing?

But why the *all the -er* construction here?

It is mostly used like this: *This incident makes this case all the more important.*

Answer (score 1):

It's an odd sentence. "Even as" ... means "at the same time", but with a hint of emphasis, and possibly opposition. It's actually rather vague in this context. The author does not come straight out and say, "in spite of being well organized, the camps are a sign of madness". Nor does he say, "It was insane to see such meticulous organization placed at the service of evil". It's almost as if he is trying to make both points at the same time. The liberators were horrified by the carnage, and equally horrified by the "careful industrial organization".

My opinion: the author is trying to sound like an Oxford graduate of the 1950's, but he doesn't quite have the literary skill to pull it off. the stuff doesn't make sense, actually.

the "All the ..er" construction is standard. example. "It was bad that I spilled my coffee on the report; that my boss saw the spill just make it all the worse."

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like madness - even as the careful industrial organization becomes all the clearer.

Normally, careful organization would not evoke the image of madness. In this case however, it is exactly what happens: an idea of utter madness emerges, while discovering the careful organization.

So in the process of discovering the careful organization, something unexpected happens, namely the discovery of madness. "Even as" is indeed used to mean "while" in the sense of "at the same time", to emphasize that this counter-intuitive thing happens: incomprehension and an idea of madness, while in the process of clarifying a carefully organized system.